# String file for Gujarati Text in Android for localization

Tags: android, localization

hello friends i want to display Gujarati text from string file so i made folder like values-gu and put string item like

```
 <item name="language">ભાષા પસંદ કરો</item>
```

when i run on device it display blank text so how can i solve it ?

my MainJava File is As Below:

```
public class CategoryActivity  extends Activity

 {
Button mButtonCurrency;
Button mButtonGoldSilverPrice;
Intent mIntent;
Locale myLocale;
Spinner mSpinnerLangeage;
public int from;
TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.choose_category);
    mIntent=getIntent();
    mButtonCurrency=(Button)findViewById(R.id.choose_category_btn_currency); 
    mTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.choose_category_txt_language);
    mButtonGoldSilverPrice=(Button)findViewById(R.id.choose_category_btn_gold_silver); 
    mSpinnerLangeage=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.choose_category_spn_language);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.language_name, R.layout.spin_layout);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    mSpinnerLangeage.setAdapter(adapter);


    mSpinnerLangeage.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(
                AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,int pos, long l) {

            from=pos;
            if(pos==1)
            {
                setLocale("en");
            }

            else if (pos==2) {
                setLocale("gu");
            }
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
    mButtonCurrency.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CurrencyConverterActivity.class);
            startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    });

    mButtonGoldSilverPrice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GetGoldAndSilverPriceActivity.class);
            mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    });

}
public void setLocale(String lang) {

    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent mIntentRefresh = new Intent(this, CategoryActivity.class);
    mIntentRefresh.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(mIntentRefresh);
}
```

My string file is include value like

```
<item name="language">ભાષા પસંદ કરો</item>
```

But it is not working in device

Comment: Right click on this xml file in Eclipse. Choose Properties. Choose Resource on the left. On the right, change Text File Encoding to "UTF-8".

Comment: @SherifelKhatib: i Done same thing whatever you post but still same issue occur!!

Comment: After you do it, open the file and re enter the value inside <item>.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib: Still not working !!!

Comment: How do you use this item? Can you post more code?

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya I thought the issue with your mSpinnerLangeage spinner, because every time when activity create  the spinner perform setOnItemSelectedListener method and choose first element.in your case its english. please try using Button and list alert dialog.

Comment: I am facing same error. Please let me know if anyone have solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/RVRaghuGujarati.TTF");   
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt)).setTypeface(font);
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt)).setText("ભાષા પસંદ કરો");
```

You need to create an folder called "fonts" in assests folder of your project. And, need to download and add the Gujarati(.ttf) font.

this will work. Pls vote me if this helps.